# Select/dropdown filter at second row of thead when I use bSortCellsTop/orderCellsTop

Tags: jquery, datatables

I try to make my first row of thead as:

- Display column name,
- Column sorting

And second row as text/dropdown filtering.

But when I want to add top row ordering using `orderCellsTop: true` or `bSortCellsTop: true`, the select/dropdown filter moved to first row of `<thead>`.

Here's my Datatables code:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ordering: false,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    initComplete: function () {
        var api = this.api();

        api.columns([2,5,7]).every( function (currentValue, index) {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
                
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( data, j ) {
                if(index == 2) //for school column
                    data = data.match(/SK (([a-zA-Z]\w+) *)+/g);
                select.append( '<option value="'+data+'">'+data+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
```

Here is how my table currently looks like:

[image: table]

**Update on changes after trying @mark_b's suggestion**
js code:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    // ordering: false,
    stateSave: true,
    // bSortCellsTop: true,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    initComplete: function () {
        const nonSearchableColNo = [0, 6, 8];
        var api = this.api();

        api.columns([2,5,7]).every( function (currentValue, index) {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $("thead tr:eq(1) tr").eq(index) )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val , true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
                
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( data, j ) {
                if(currentValue == 2) { //for school column 
                    data = data.match(/SK (([a-zA-Z]\w+) *)+/g);
                }
                select.append( '<option value="'+data+'">'+data+'</option>' )

            } );
        } );
    }
});
```

Table screenshot:
[image: table screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So DataTables by default has the "last" row in the `thead` as the header. By setting `orderCellsTop: true` you are telling it to use the "first" row instead (which will be used for sorting etc). But this is also applied when you use the `column.header()` function. So DataTables is adding the filter to the header, which is now the top row.

Change your `appendTo` to add the column filters to the second row in the your `thead`:

```js
.appendTo( $("thead tr:eq(1) th").eq(index) )
```

Also I would recommend you use `td` instead of `th` for the second row in your header because DataTables allocates a space inside the `th` cell for the sorting arrows whether they are present or not. By using `td` instead your filter input will fill the cell.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on:

- added a `tr` of `td`s and change all occurrences of `th` into `td` 
- change the `appendTo()` function as suggested
but the `select` dropdown filter is not working

Comment: You can refer to my latest update above.

Comment: @hweiu321 your `$("thead tr:eq(1) tr")` DOM selector is looking for a table row inside a table row. Change the last two characters to `td`.